# MVC Web Application staged conversion to Angular

Tags: angular, asp.net-mvc

I have an existing MVC application with lots of content. I want to convert this to an Angular application, adding any new pages as Angular and converting existing pages when time permits. It's not feasible to simply put time into converting the whole application.

Basically this means that I am trying to run Angular pages and MVC views in the same application but I don't even know if that's possible. I have found, for example, a course on Pluralsight where an MVC app is converted but not bit-by-bit with existing MVC views still working alongside new Angular pages.

How can routing be made to work for instance?

I am searching everywhere for some help, without success, so decided to post the question here in the meantime.

Answer (score 0):

This was reasonably simple.

I created a specific layout view for angular which provides the links to the angular specific scripts and css files.

Then create a view to host the angular pages - use the new layout page with this view and put your angular root tag into this page.

Then provide an mvc route that serves up this new view when no other url pattern (from your existing mvc pages) matches.

Then in your angular routing be sure not to specify routes that may clash with the mvc urls.

Over time I should be able to remove all the mvc plumbing finally do a conversion to a cleaner angular architecture.